# How to write a Date Code In vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

VB CODE.

```
dteFrom = Format(CDate(Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & "01"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
dteTo = Format(CDate(Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" &  DaysInMonth(dteFrom)), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

I copy this code in VB.NET, It showing error (of Date)

```
dteFrom = Format(CDate(Year(Of Date)() & "-" & Month(Of Date)() & "-" & "01"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
dteTo = Format(CDate(Year(Of Date)() & "-" & Month(Of Date)() & "-" & DaysInMonth(dteFrom)), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Can any one Help to solve this problem.

Need VB.Net Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the closest to your original code:

```
dteFrom = Format(CDate(Year(Date.Today) & "-" & Month(Date.Today) & "-" & "01"), "yyyy-MM-dd")
dteTo = Format(CDate(Year(Date.Today) & "-" & Month(Date.Today) & "-" & Date.DaysInMonth(Year(Date.Today), Month(Date.Today))), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

This will be a more ".NET" way to do it :

```
dteFrom = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM}-01", Date.Today)
dteTo = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM}-{1:00}", Date.Today, Date.DaysInMonth(Year(Date.Today), Month(Date.Today)) )
```

Comment: Note that the format string is uppercase **M** for month. Lowercase **m** is minutes. The VB6 function was "smart" and distinguished between minutes and month based on the logic in the pattern (looks like a date - month, looks like a time - minutes). In .NET you have to distinguish between upper and lowercase, just as for the String.Format function.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want two strings representing the first and last days of the current month. In that case you can do the following:

```
Dim today As Date = Date.Today
Dim desiredFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd"

Dim fromDate As Date = New Date(today.Year, today.Month, 1)
Dim dteFrom As String = fromDate.ToString(desiredFormat)

Dim toDate As Date = fromDate.AddDays(Date.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month) - 1)
Dim dteTo As String = toDate.ToString(desiredFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Dim dateString as String = string.format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month, 1))
```

Comment: Those 'm's need to be capitalized; lower case will give you minutes.